# Link that submits a form via jquery is sometimes not firing

Tags: jquery, events, forms, hyperlink, submit

I have a link that is submitting a huge form, with the following code:

```
$('#the_link').click(function() {
   $('#the_form').submit();
   return false;
});
```

However, sometimes (about 3rd of the time I'd guess) the form isn't submitting and and nothing is happening. Just click and nothing.

Am I missing something? Is the code that's linking the link and the form correct or am I setting up some race condition or something?

Cheers.

Comment: what do you mean "sometimes (about 3rd of the time I'd guess)", give us all your way to troubleshoot. Are you sure this is happing when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange one but I've fixed it.

It was actually a css problem, the link on :active became position:relative; and moved 1px down.

For some reason this sometimes stopped the link from firing. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a guess, but try using [`e.preventDefualt()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of `return false;` in the `click` handler. It would seem that this would target the specific event object more directly.

```
$('#the_link').click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#the_form').submit();
});
```

*(If the purpose of `return false;` was also to prevent event bubbling, then add `e.stopPropagation()` as well.)*

Comment: that what is this going to help him if the form is not submitted.

Comment: @tsegay: The point is (though speculative) that `return false` may somehow be canceling the form submission. There's nothing else to work from in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the document is fully loaded.

You can use `firbug` on `firefox` to test.

Comment: If the issue is with a `click` event, then it would be unlikely that someone would be able to perform a click before the DOM is completely loaded.